# Cannot inflate the listview inside fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have created a fragment named **HomeFragment** which implements swipeRefreshLayout.
What I'm trying to do is,I'm getting a json array from server and I'm extracting information from the json and inflating the layout using custom adapter extending array adapter inside **HomeFragment** and also I have a **MenuActivity.java** which have 5 buttons inside linear layout,when the button is clicked the fragment changes
Now when I'm running the application neither the buttons are changing the fragment on click nor the layout is inflated.

**Logcat**

```
06-18 11:16:02.803 994-994/com.example.udeys.theindianroute E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.example.udeys.theindianroute.MenuActivity.access$super
06-18 11:16:02.813 994-994/com.example.udeys.theindianroute E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.example.udeys.theindianroute.MenuActivity.access$super
06-18 11:16:02.813 994-994/com.example.udeys.theindianroute E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.session.MediaController', referenced from method com.example.udeys.theindianroute.MenuActivity.access$super
06-18 11:16:02.813 994-994/com.example.udeys.theindianroute E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.widget.Toolbar', referenced from method com.example.udeys.theindianroute.MenuActivity.access$super
06-18 11:16:02.813 994-994/com.example.udeys.theindianroute E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription', referenced from method com.example.udeys.theindianroute.MenuActivity.access$super
06-18 11:16:02.823 994-994/com.example.udeys.theindianroute E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.example.udeys.theindianroute.MenuActivity.access$super
06-18 11:16:02.823 994-994/com.example.udeys.theindianroute E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.example.udeys.theindianroute.MenuActivity.access$super
06-18 11:16:02.823 994-994/com.example.udeys.theindianroute E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.example.udeys.theindianroute.MenuActivity.access$super
06-18 11:16:02.833 994-994/com.example.udeys.theindianroute E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.assist.AssistContent', referenced from method com.example.udeys.theindianroute.MenuActivity.access$super
06-18 11:16:02.833 994-994/com.example.udeys.theindianroute E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.SearchEvent', referenced from method com.example.udeys.theindianroute.MenuActivity.access$super
06-18 11:16:02.833 994-994/com.example.udeys.theindianroute E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.example.udeys.theindianroute.MenuActivity.access$super
06-18 11:16:02.973 994-994/com.example.udeys.theindianroute E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.example.udeys.theindianroute.EmptyFragment.access$super
06-18 11:16:02.973 994-994/com.example.udeys.theindianroute E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.example.udeys.theindianroute.EmptyFragment.access$super
06-18 11:16:02.983 994-994/com.example.udeys.theindianroute E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.example.udeys.theindianroute.HomeFragment.access$super
06-18 11:16:02.983 994-994/com.example.udeys.theindianroute E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.example.udeys.theindianroute.HomeFragment.access$super
06-18 11:16:03.033 994-994/com.example.udeys.theindianroute E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.udeys.theindianroute, PID: 994
                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.udeys.theindianroute/com.example.udeys.theindianroute.MenuActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class
                                                                                  at android.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:402)
                                                                                  at android.app.ListFragment.onViewCreated(ListFragment.java:203)
                                                                                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:904)
                                                                                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
                                                                                  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
                                                                                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5240)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**MenuActivity.java**

```
package com.example.udeys.theindianroute;

import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


    ImageButton hm, srch, pst, notif, prfl;
    FragmentTransaction ft;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
        initFragments();

        hm = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.home);
        srch = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.trip);
        pst = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.post);
        notif = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.notification);
        prfl = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.profile);


        hm.setOnClickListener(this);
        srch.setOnClickListener(this);
        pst.setOnClickListener(this);
        notif.setOnClickListener(this);
        prfl.setOnClickListener(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.home:
                ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.fragment_1, new HomeFragment());
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                ft.commit();
                break;
            case R.id.trip:
                ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.fragment_1, new TripFragment());
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                ft.commit();
                break;
            case R.id.post:
                ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.fragment_1, new PostFragment());
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                ft.commit();
                break;
            case R.id.notification:
                ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.fragment_1, new NotificationFragment());
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                ft.commit();
                break;
            case R.id.profile:
                ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.fragment_1, new ProfileFragment());
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                ft.commit();
                break;
        }

    }

    private void initFragments() {
        ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.fragment_1, new HomeFragment());
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        //ft.hide(mGalleryFragment);
        ft.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                // User chose the "Settings" item, show the app settings UI...
                return true;


            default:
                // If we got here, the user's action was not recognized.
                // Invoke the superclass to handle it.
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }
}
```

**HomeFragment.java**

```
package com.example.udeys.theindianroute;

/**
 * Created by udeys on 6/17/2016.
 */

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.udeys.theindianroute.utils.PostAdapter;
import com.example.udeys.theindianroute.utils.posts;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.TextHttpResponseHandler;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {
    PostAdapter PostAdapter;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    ListView datalist;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.homefragment, container, false);
        datalist = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.users_posts);
        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        datalist.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                if (datalist.getChildAt(0) != null) {
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(datalist.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0 && datalist.getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0);
                }
            }
        });
        Typeface cFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "SAMARN__.TTF");
        Typeface fontAwesome = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
        PostAdapter = new PostAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.timelinerowlayout, cFont, fontAwesome);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        /**
         * Showing Swipe Refresh animation on activity create
         * As animation won't start on onCreate, post runnable is used
         */
        swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                                        bindData();
                                    }
                                }
        );

    }

    /**
     * This method is called when swipe refresh is pulled down
     */
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        bindData();
    }


    public void bindData() {


        try {
            AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient(true, 80, 443);
            client.get("http://indianroute.roms4all.com/fetch_post.php", new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String res) {
                            decodeJson(res);

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String res, Throwable t) {
                            // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + res, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
            );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }

    private void decodeJson(String result) {
        try {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
            JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray(result);
            String username, story, picture, check_in, userprofilePicture;
            for (int count = 0; count < jArr.length(); count++) {
                JSONObject obj = jArr.getJSONObject(count);
                username = obj.getString("username");
                story = obj.getString("story");
                picture = obj.getString("picture");
                check_in = obj.getString("check_in");
                userprofilePicture = obj.getString("userprofilePicture");
                posts posts = new posts(username, story, picture, check_in, userprofilePicture);
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                PostAdapter.add(posts);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**homefragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.example.gitesh.timeline.MainActivity">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/users_posts"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: Please read this article before asking any question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your error is in `ListFragment.java:402` at this line. Why would you post the HomeFragment and not ListFragment..? Please delete the former, and post only the latter.